# Id of edittext in searchable app

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to implement search view in my app that when user clicked on search button on the device search data. But i dont know how can set ID to default search edittext and how can get the ID of that.I know get ID of edittext by findviewbyid but i dont know ID of that edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your edittext in the xml file exactly where you want it to appeare and set visibility to "gone" and also set and id for it.
Ex:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

When you want it to appear (when you press the search button I guess) set the visibility to visible.
Ex: edittext..setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Now your edittext is visible and the user can add an input. Get the input with getText().toString() and when you want it gone set visibility back to gone.

Comment: i dont add dynamically.when you press search button in your devise one edittext and button appear, i want id of that edittext,

Comment: set it in the xml android:id="@+id/whatever"

Comment: or your problem is hot to link to the id?

Comment: where can i put this id??? i dont define any xml file to that, i think this is system defined. when u add edittext into xml file then you can add id, i have one xml file in layout that nothing have and one another xml file into xml folder that searchable.

Comment: your english is confusing me but I think I understand what you need, I'll edit my post

Comment: its good idea, but when i set visibility ti view.visibility edittext not appeard, ( text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do what you want:-
1. by android default way using following urls:-
[android search setup](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)
[android search dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

2.using Custom view as search view In Action bar(So you can search from any of activity OR fragments):-
add a menu in your application menu.xml file

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbarsearchlayout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:title="Search"/>
```

following is actionbarsearchlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:imeActionLabel="search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do the following in where you inflate option menu. Inside OnOptionitemSelected()

```
case R.id.search:
        View view = item.getActionView();

        final EditText search = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.searchTitle);
        search.setText("");
search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (event != null) {
                    if (event.getAction() != 
KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        return handled;
                    } else if (actionId ==
EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                            || event.getKeyCode() ==
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                        //do whatever you want to search
//with query 
                        handled = true;
                        InputMethodManager imm =
  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(


  search.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this please:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.your_needed_view:
                    // your actions
                    break;}}
```

and then use `setOnClickListener()`

Comment: specify in your xml file `android:id="@+id/your_needed_view"`

Comment: i dont add edittext in my program that can see that, i use default edittext that when you clicked search button in your android device, and want id of that